# Null pointer exception on existing tag XML Java

Tags: java, xml

I am using the XML file [here](http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByNameXML?StationDesc=Dublin%20Pearse)

I have the following code:

```
        Document doc = (Document) docBuilder.parse(new URL("http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByNameXML?StationDesc=" + dstation).openStream());

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList trains = doc.getElementsByTagName("objStationData");

        for(int i = 0; i<trains.getLength(); i++){

                if(trains.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Direction").getTextContent().trim().equals("Northbound")){

                    System.out.println(trains.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Destination").getTextContent().trim());
                }
            }
```

I get a Null Pointer exception on the if statement. Why is this? The objects exist in the XML file as you can see in the link above.

Comment: Since `Direction` is not an attribute I am not surprised that a null is thrown.

Comment: @markbernard Thanks for the answer. I want to get the text inside the tag `Direction` but `getElementByTagName()` didn't seem to work. So I tried the `getAttribute()`. What other alternative is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. Since you know the structure of the XML and you are calling `getElementsByTagName` you know that you can safely cast the nodes from `NodeList` to `Element` objects.

```
Document doc = (Document) docBuilder.parse(new URL("http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByNameXML?StationDesc=" + dstation).openStream());
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList trains = doc.getElementsByTagName("objStationData");
for(int i = 0; i<trains.getLength(); i++){
    Element objStationDataElement = (Element)trains.item(i);
    Element directionElement = objStationDataElement.getElementsByTagName("Direction").item(0);
    if(directionElement.getTextContent().trim().equals("Northbound")){
        Element destinationElement = (Element)objStationDataElement.getElementsByTagName("Destination").item(0);
        System.out.println(destinationElement.getTextContent().trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. In my original attempt I just left out the `.item(0)` .. whoops